# Linux support for RTP-MIDI?

Tags: audio, macintosh, music

I have been spoiled by the ease with which I can connect my iPad up to MIDI applications on my Macbook using the native support for midi-over-the-network (apparently RTP-MIDI) provided by the CoreMIDI subsystem in both OS X and iOS.

Is there a compatible Linux implementation?  I have found some tantalizing references out there that indicate there *may* be one, but I haven't been able to find any concrete information.

Answer (score 5):

The original reference implementation of the RTP-MIDI protocol (originally specified in [RFC4695](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4695) - now updated to [RFC6295](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6295)) from the guys who developed it is available as part of an older version of their [sfront](http://web.archive.org/web/20120804033903/http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/%7Elazzaro/sa/sfman/user/cmdline/index.html#network) software.

It seems that the Wikipedia page on [RTP-MIDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTP-MIDI#Implementations) now has a good list available implementations.

A more up to date implementation is available in the  Java based [nmj](http://www.humatic.de/htools/nmj) library, which apparently works with iOS: http://www.humatic.de/htools/nmj

There was (now defunct) the interesting [scenic](https://web.archive.org/web/20161011022626/http://code.sat.qc.ca/redmine/projects/scenic) project that contains Python based rtpmidi support (from which the now discontinued midistream Debian package was derived). In the Scenic source tree the actual midistream python application is here scenic/py/scripts/midistream.in, and the associated library may be found here: scenic/py/rtpmidi

It is also possible to use [JACK](http://www.jackaudio.org/) to send MIDI but you need to run JACK on all machines (so for iOS you'll need an app that supports JACK).

Some more Windows based software (free but not open source): http://www.tobias-erichsen.de/software.html

Update 2018: There's now a Node based implementation of [rtpMIDI](https://github.com/jdachtera/node-rtpmidi) and also the [Arduino-AppleMIDI-Library](https://github.com/lathoub/Arduino-AppleMidi-Library) that may be possible to port to Linux.

Update 2019: A new implementation aimed at the Raspberry Pi called [RaveloxMIDI](https://github.com/ravelox/pimidi) has become available which seems like it will run on Debian/Centos Linux as well.

**Update 2020**: Another Linux RTP-MIDI library: [rtpmidid](https://github.com/davidmoreno/rtpmidid) and a Python based one: [pymidi](https://github.com/mik3y/pymidi)

Answer (score 3):

One other alternative is to use a MIDI router box with USB-MIDI and Ethernet (RTP-MIDI) interfaces. You attaches the USB connection to your linux machine just like any USB/MIDI interfaces. Then, data received on the virtual USB MIDI ports are forwarded to the opened RTP-MIDI sessions (and vice-versa) by the box. At least, one product ([Cinara MidiGateway](http://www.cinaratech.com/info/fr/productsmenu-fr/midigateway-fr)) is doing that kind of functions. This solution does not require any kind of specific software running on the host, and it preserves compatibility with other RTP-MIDI devices.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like several [iConnectivity products](https://www.iconnectivity.com/products/midi/mio4) are set up to do turnkey RTP-MIDI (Ethernet MIDI) as well.